# Difference between import { ref } from 'vue' vs '@vue/reactivity'?

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

The code below is for a simple counter component, but it will not work, that is, `increment()` and `decrement()` do change the value, but the template doesn't render the change.

The reason is because of the import statement. If I instead used `import { ref } from 'vue';` it would work as expected. What is the difference between `vue` and `@vue/reactivity`?

I mainly ask because I am using the [Vetur](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur) extension in VSCode, and when I type `ref`, it offers to import it for me, but it imports it from `@vue/reactivity`. The same with `reactive`.

I tried Googling for "@vue/reactivity", but it searches for the words "vue reactivity" instead, and that's not specific enough to help me find out what `@vue/reactivity` is.

```
<template>
  <div>{{counter}}</div>
  <button @click="decrement">-</button>
  <button @click="increment">+</button>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from '@vue/reactivity';

export default {
  setup(){
    const counter = ref(0);

    const increment = function(){
      counter.value++;
    }
    const decrement = function(){
      counter.value--;
    }

    return {
      counter,
      increment,
      decrement
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's just the reactivity system published as a standalone package.  The source is in the main github repo.  See [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/tree/master/packages/reactivity#readme).

Comment: Thanks for the link. The question remains though, if they're the same thing, then in my code sample why does one work and the other not?

Comment: Well the repo says you shouldn't use the standalone along side the bundled version because they use different internal storage.  I'm surprised by default you can even import from that as it's not a normal dependency when creating a fresh project from the vue-cli.